# Распарасить Json в массив объектов

Tags: javascript, json

Необходимо распарсить данные пользователей приходящие с сервера в формате json, на сервере их собираю и конвертирую в json с помощью библиотеки Gson, получаю формат:
`[{"Name":"Ivan","Surname":"Ivanovich","Date":"Ivanov","Email":"banan03112000@gmail.com","Socials":"vk.com/example"},{"Name":"Ivanoa","Surname":"Ivanovicha","Date":"Ivanov","Email":"banan03112000@gmail.com","Socials":"vk.com/example"}]`

JSON.parse в js мне выдает не данные которые мне надо а выводит цифры 0,1,2,3... по количеству объектов. Подскажите как правильно распарсить данные в массив объектов, чтобы получился формат:

```
array[0] = Obj1(в нем свои данные)
array[1] = Obj1(тут другие данные) и тд
```

Мой код js

```
$(function (){
   let Params = {};

   Params.Name= null;
   Params.Surname= null;
   Params.Date= null;
   Params.Socials= null;
   Params.Email= null;

   let OutputArray;

   $("#GetInfoButton").on('click',function (){
       $.post("list", function (data) {
           OutputArray = JSON.parse(data);
       });

       for(let item in OutputArray){
           console.log(item+"\n");
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OutputArray = JSON.parse(data);
OutputArray.forEach(item => console.log(item.Name + " " + item.Surname));
```